# Django how to delete user's profile and posts and all assocation after user deleted?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I'm writing a django project. And want to know after user deletes his own account, is there a way django build-in to auto delete all object related to this user(e.g. some generic foreign_key)? Or I should use signal "post_delete" to delete every objects related?

Comment: Are you sure the related objects aren't already being deleted? Non-nullable ForeignKeys must be deleted to avoid an IntegrityError, and IIRC Django will do so by default. By generic foreign key, do you mean [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) specifically? Because that gets more complicated.

Comment: @AdamKG I think I didn't mean GenericForeignKey specifically here. What I mean is the ON DELETE CASCADE which I already got an answer. I have not understood clearly what GenericForeignKey does as long as Contenttype, I'm studying. Another question which maybe not relative to this one, but I want to ask is, I found some user profile implementation, they all use ForeignKey instead of OneToOne. Are they suppose a many-to-one relation here or it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE -- in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

```
b = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
# This will delete the Blog and all of its Entry objects.
b.delete()
```

Answer (score 7):

Django recommends not deleting users since foreign keys will break.  It's for this reason that they included the is_active method.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

Comment: This is an old and possibly outdated recommendation and the link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

You should explicitly delete all of the generic foreign key references to the original object before you delete the original object.  For example

```
Image.objects.filter( object_id=object_to_be_deleted.id,content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(bject_to_be_deleted.get_profile() )).delete()
object_to_be_deleted.delete()
```

The cascading delete is great when it works, for example, for one-to-one relationships in the models, but it doesn't seem to work for generic foreign key relationships.

Comment: Although I agree with your recommendation, the statement "it doesn't seem to work for generic foreign key relationships" needs further explanation as this is not the usual case.

Comment: @Wtower This was true in 2012 (Django 1.4?) but it appears from the documentation ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations ) that now "if you delete an object that has a GenericRelation, any objects which have a GenericForeignKey pointing at it will be deleted as well" which may have been a Django 1.7 change.

Comment: @MarkChackerian I see, thanks for the info and for the answer.